# Get ReactJs component width after mount

Tags: reactjs, width, react-leaflet

I am using react-leaflet map for showing custom map (non-geographical)
Also, map size is dynamical and I need to calculate zoom level depending on the ratio between component and map size.

Is there a reactJs native way to calculate loaded component size?

Comment: Assuming your using a full screen map this might assist you https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-window-dimensions

Comment: No, it will be map on page rendered in componet. But I will check this link.

Comment: You could ofcourse out the map in a div? And then get the dimensions like so var div = $("#myDiv"); (".height(): " + div.height()); unless that's not possible

Comment: You can use react measure, check this out : https://github.com/souporserious/react-measure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would wrap your component inside of a `div` that wraps around your react-leaflet.

```
<div
  style={{display: 'inline'}}
>
  ... your leaflet
</div>
```

And add a Ref, as @trixn suggested. Note: Your component must be Stateful in order to use Refs.

```
<div
  style={{display: 'inline'}}
  ref={leaflet => { this.leaflet = leaflet } }
>
  ... your leaflet
</div>
```

Then create/modify the `componentDidMount()` lifecycle method:

```
componentDidMount() {
  console.log(this.leaflet.offsetWidth); // Rounded value of the width
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain a reference to the underlying DOM element of a component. From there you can get your needed rendered size info. See [Refs and the DOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) in the react docs for details.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      clientRect: {},
    };
  }

  ref = node => node && this.setState({clientRect: node.getBoundingClientRect()});

  render() {
    return(
      <div
        style={{ width: '50px', height: '50px' }}
        ref={this.ref}
      >
        {JSON.stringify(this.state.clientRect)}
  </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is put your component in a `div` with 100% width and height as style and then retrive the actual dimensions.

So in your wrapper component you would have:

```
getDimensions = () => {
    if (!this.contentDiv) return;
    const rect = this.contentDiv.getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log(rect.width);
    console.log(rect.height);
};
```

And in the render method

```
<div
    ref={ref => {
        this.contentDiv = ref;
    }}
    style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
>
    {content}
</div>
```